# Markup for table row titles in html

Tags: html, html-table

Some tables have both column names and row names. ie:

```
         Bob  Bill
Game A    4    6
Game B    2    7
```

The column names (Bob, Bill) are usually marked up using `thead` and `th`. Is there any special markup for the row names (Game A, Game B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<th>
```

in place of

```
 <td>
```

for the first column.

Answer (score 1):

nope, there is only `th` for header cells and `td` for body cells.  Both of them appear inside a `tr` element (row).

In your case, you will have three columns.  In the header, the first `th` will be empty.  In the body, the first `td` will contain your row names, with the next two `td`'s containing, respectively, the data for Bob and Bill.

Answer (score 1):

game a and game b are headers too; you should place them into a th as well...most browsers default th to bold, however you can style table elements however you look.

if you really want to get accessible with it, you can denote the th as having a scope of row, as well as place headers and ids for the corresponding content.